# Передать переменную из sql запроса в php

Tags: mysql

Есть вот такой код:

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id='1'");
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
$test = $row["id"];
}
```

Как мне передать переменную далее в php скрипт? Если пишу $test, то ничего не выходит.

Answer (score 1):

Понял решение:

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id='1'");
$data = array();
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
$data[] = $row["id"];
}

echo $data[0]
```